# Reusing a SerialPort object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using the node js  serialport package (https://serialport.io/docs/).

I create the following serial port object :

```
var port = new SerialPort(data.device.hostPort, {
                baudRate: 115200, 
                autoOpen: false,
                }
           );
```

I save this object on a json file, so that later i can reuse it.
However after retrieving the data inside the json file and parsing it I can't use the serial port object methods, I try to use:

```
port.open(function(err){
    if(err){
        return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
    }
});
```

But i get an error saying that the open method is not recognized.
Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is that **you are trying to run before learning to walk**. You think you understand some things (like JSON and classes) and trying to move ahead; but it is clear that you lack some basic knowledges which lead you to understand wrong beacuse you are starting from a deficient base.

1. Learn basics about [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) on JavaScript.
2. Learn what is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). It's a subset of JavaScript, and only includes some primitive data.
3. Learn about [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), prototype and [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on JavaScript.
4. Learn about [serialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serialization).

And I think that then, you may understand why **what you are trying to do is not possible the way you're attempting to do so**. Even more, usually physical resources can't be serialized without a unique identifier.

On the other hand, your not stating what is the problem you're not capable of solving, just what you attempt and the result you get. That's just half the question.

If you just want to connect to the "same" port the same way, you just need to store the information to reconstruct it and some function to do so: Probably you'll need:

- The name of the port (the unique identifier!!): `data.device.hostPort`
- The configuration: `{baudRate: 115200, autoOpen: false}`

Also, you must consider that:

- Maybe there is another informarion you'll need to store, more related with the specifics of your problem domain.
- Some information may change after initial configuration. The best approach is to have a function that gets a SerialPort, reads the relevant properties and returns a serialized object. Then you make another function to reverse the operation, which will invoke the SerialPort constructor.
- If you're mixing serialized classes, you may need some way to indicate the class. Also, if by accident you send another object, you can detect it and throw a more useful error.